# cordova File Transfer plugin not uploading video to Server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

1. I'm creating an Hybrid app in which I want to upload video to
   server. Sometimes it uploads the video to the server but most of the
   time Plugin shows the uploading progress to 99% and then it gives
   null in success callback. 
       Thanks in advance. :-)

   ```
   /********* OPENING CAMERA TO CPTURE VIDEO ***********/
   function make_Video()
   {
       // capture callback
       var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {

           var i, len , video_path;

           if(mediaFiles.length > 0)
           {

               for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1)
               {
                   video_path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

                   Upload_Video(video_path);

               }

           }

       };

       // capture error callback
       var captureError = function(error)
       {
         console.log('Error Code: ' + error.code);
       };
   navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { quality: 100,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

   }

   /****************STORING VIDEO ON SERVER******************/
   function Upload_Video(video_path)
   {
       var server =  server_link; // MY SERVER LINK
       var params = {'user_id':logged_in_user_id,'action':'update_intro_video'};

       if (server)
       {

               // Specify transfer options
               $('#modal_first_line').text(0+" %"+" Uploaded");
               $('#new_modal').show();
               var options         = new FileUploadOptions();
               options.fileKey     = "user_video";

         options.fileName = video_path.substr(video_path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

               options.mimeType    = "video/mp4";
               options.chunkedMode = false;
               options.httpMethod  = "POST";
               options.params      = params;
               // Transfer picture to server
               var ft = new FileTransfer();


    //progree bar
    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

   if (progressEvent.lengthComputable){  var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100); $('#modal_first_line').text(perc+" %"+"
   Uploaded"); } else {$('#new_modal').hide();
          console.log("sorry! Upload Failed..."); }  };

               ft.upload(video_path, encodeURI(server) , function(data) {
                           $('#new_modal').hide();
                           console.log("SERVER RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                         },
                         function(error)
                         {
                           $('#new_modal').hide();
                           console.log("sorry! Upload Failed...");
                         }, options);
       }

       else{
               $('#new_modal').hide();
               console.log("sorry! Can't Upload File.");;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.
   The Problem was at server end. Configuration was making
    trouble. post_max_size was set to 8Mb, so when limit of video
    exceeds to 8MB, server was not allowing to save the video. I
    increased the post_max_size to 100MB. To Increase the post_max_size
    , I did the following steps
     1. I Created a file **.user.ini** in the root directory
     2. I placed the following code inside this file
  file_uploads = O post_max_size = 100M  upload_max_filesize
    = 200M

```
Hope it will help someone.
```